# Fixed div background overlapping browser scrollbars

Tags: css, html, scrollbar, overlap, fixed

Very strange behavior that I haven't seen before.

I have a fixed position div that has a transparent png background image.  The z-index is set to -1 so that content can scroll over the fixed image with the scrollbars.

I have it positioned with the bottom and right at 0px, but the image overlaps the scrollbars (on FF and Safari, anyway.)

Here's the link:

http://adamjcas.www59.a2hosting.com/pg/show/id/4

CSS:

```
#plants /*for the cut paper plants in the background*/
{
    background: transparent url(../background_images/plants.png) no-repeat;                                         
    bottom:0px;
    right:0px;
    z-index: -1;
    position:fixed;
    height:691px;
    width:475px;        
}
```

One hack I used was to use 
    right: 16px;

Which worked fine, as there is always (probably) a right scrollbar.  But the bottom scroll is only sometimes there.  Is this a simple CSS issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That was a strange issue. But I figured out that the scroll bar was not from the browser but instead from the parent div which had `overflow: auto`.

This is how I fixed that. Change the style for `div id="rightpanel"` to remove the `overflow: auto;`.

Then update the `#rightcontent` styles as follows:

```
#rightcontent {
    left: 445px;
    padding-top: 127px;
    position: relative;
    width: 650px;
}
```

Hopefully that should fix the issue for all browsers. Besides that I also found the browsers complaining about not finding Cufon.js. You might want to look into that as well.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  The overflow was definitely the problem; when I made these changes it seemed to work on Firefox (except the background stopped repeating) but it fails in Chrome.  Thanks for putting me on the right track; I'll keep at it and post the results.

Comment: @Adam, Strange that seemed to work fine for me on Chrome, FF and IE. Did you make the changes to the `rightContent` as well?

Comment: I did.  There's more going on though; the background of the #rightcontent div stopped before the bottom; the content was overflowing it.  I'm going to post the final code when I get it done (minor issue at the moment on the greater list), but your pointing out the scrollbars were div overflow was what I needed.

Comment: I was having the same issue. The scrollbar was from html, body{ overflow: auto }