# How can I get a DIV to resize when the browser resizes?

Tags: html, css

Alrighty, this is my first question, of probably many to come.

I have a div that is set to be 70% of the page, but when I resize my browser to a smaller size, some content in that div goes below the bottom of the page. It's hard to explain.

The scroll bar goes below the bottom of the page too.

This is my css code for that div

```
#header {
position: fixed;
width:100%;
height:100%;
z-index: 90;
overflow:auto;
}



#navigation {
margin-top:20px;
display:block;
list-style:none;
z-index:3;
margin-bottom:10px;
}

#navigation a{  
margin-top:0;
color: #444;
display: block;
background: #fff;
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
line-height: 50px;
padding: 0px 10px;
text-transform: uppercase;
margin-bottom: 6px;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
font-family: 'Cinzel', serif;
font-weight:600;
font-size: 19px;
text-align:center;
}


.panel{ 
overflow:auto;
right: 40px;
left: 40px;
height:70%;
position: fixed;
margin-top: -150%;
margin-bottom:auto;
background-color: #008aff;
opacity: 0;
z-index:2;
-webkit-transition: opacity .6s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: opacity .6s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: opacity .6s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: opacity .6s ease-in-out;
transition: opacity .6s ease-in-out;
```

and the html file

```
<div id="header">
            <div id="navigation">
                <table align="center">
                    <tr>
                        <th width="300px" align="center">
                            <img src="logo.png" height="165px">
                        </th>

                        <th width="140px" align="center"><a id="link-home" href="#home">Home</a></th>
                        <th width="140px" align="center"><a id="link-portfolio" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></th>
                        <th width="140px" align="center"><a id="link-services" href="#services">Services</a></th>
                        <th width="140px" align="center"><a id="link-about" href="#about">About</a></th>
                        <th width="140px" align="center"><a id="link-contact" href="#contact">Contact</a></th>
                    </tr>                        
                </table>
            </div>
            <!-- main content -->
            <div class="main">

                    <!-- Home -->
                <div id="home" class="panel">
                        <h2>Home</h2>
                        <p></p>
                </div>
                <!-- /Home -->

                <!-- Portfolio -->
                <div id="portfolio" class="panel">
                        <h2>Portfolio</h2>
                        <p>What I&rsquo;ve Done</p>
                </div>
                <!-- /Portfolio -->

                <!-- Services -->
                <div id="services" class="panel">
                        <h2>Services</h2>
                        <p>
                            - Line 1<br>
                            - Line 2<br>
                            - Line 3<br>
                            - Line 4<br>
                            - Line 5<br>
                            - Line 6<br>
                            - Line 7<br>
                            - Line 8<br>
                            - Line 9<br>
                            - Line 10<br>
                            - Line 11<br>
                            - Line 12<br>
                            - Line 13<br>
                            - Line 14<br>
                            - Line 15<br>
                            - Line 16<br>
                            - Line 17<br>
                            - Line 18<br>
                            - Line 19<br>
                            - Line 20<br>

                        </p>
                </div>
                <!-- /services -->


                <!-- About -->
                <div id="about" class="panel">
                        <h2>About Brem Media</h2>
                        <p>
                            Been in the Game a while!
                        </p>
                </div>
                <!-- /about -->


                <!-- Contact -->
                <div id="contact" class="panel">
                        <h2>Contact</h2>
                        <p>
                            Phone: 519.991.3671<br>
                            E-Mail: info@bremmedia.com
                        </p>
                </div>
                <!-- /Contact -->



            </div>
            <!-- ip-main -->



        </div>
        <!-- header -->
```

Comment: Golden rule: Don't tell me, show me! Create a Fiddle with the code or post it using stackoverflow's javascript example

Comment: your code have some crazy values like `margin-top: -150%;` and `opacity: 0;` which have nothing to do with the current question.

Comment: You aren't showing enough to represent the problem. Your CSS goes to which element?

Comment: I tried to post a picture but I'm a new member so I can't yet.

Comment: @Rob you're right it could get applied to any of the elements, but according to the post eich states he has a div with 70% height, I can assume he mesnt the div "services"

Comment: The css goes to the 'panel' div.

Comment: you could post a jsfiddle [**like this**](https://jsfiddle.net/seh73e2g/)

Comment: Brian, you can always post a Fiddle link, as I stated above.

Comment: Fiddles come and go. The code must be here for future's sake.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are doing well! I replicated your setup on my own end. There are a few things that weren't working well. First of all, the content is hidden for two reasons:

1. Opacity is set to 0 (invisible)
2. Margin-top: -150%
   (these were mentioned in the comments)

What I did is I eliminated these CSS values so that I could see you div. To my surprise, the scaling is on point. What I think you are trying to say is this:

[View on my browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7gNI.png)

This is Vivaldi (Chronium based browser) running your code.

Comment: I feel like your problem may be browser based.

Comment: Hey there, I am well. How are you? I took out those two lines. I'm trying to work some code I found. Anyways, It's still doing the same thing. If you go to bremmedia.com, and go to services, then resize your browser. You should see what i'm talking about

Comment: @BrianBrem I understand. I have reason to believe it is your z-index causing the issue here. I thought it was a z-index issue but I was wrong. Check out this article on this website: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812752/fixed-div-background-overlapping-browser-scrollbars

Comment: Removed the overflow on the parent divs. Still same result.